# Ionic pages transition

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have 5 different pages. In order to go to next page I use `this.navCtrl.push(PageX)` and `this.navCtrl.pop()` to go to previous one but I'd need to go to Page2 after Page5 and restart the navigation, I mean, being in Page2 if I do `pop()` I should go to Page1.

Is this possible?

Comment: naCtrl.setRoot and it will restart the stack with new root

Comment: Cool, that works. But how can I setRoot(Page2) and still having the option to go to Page1?

Comment: Ok, I don't know why but I got that working with  const index = this.viewCtrl.index - 1;  this.navCtrl.remove(4, index);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you are in Page5/Last page, do:

```
const index = this.viewCtrl.index - 3; // Number of pages to remove between last page and page3
this.navCtrl.remove(3,index); // This will remove pages between 2 and last page from stack
this.navCtrl.pop(); // This will pop the last page and take you to 'Page2'.
```

Comment: Not the most optimal solution. What would happen if I need to add new pages between 2-5? I'd have to modify this remove, right?

Comment: But how do you know you want to remove 3 pages? If we add more pages between 2-5 we'd have to modify this.

Comment: 3 is the index of the page after 'Page 2'

Comment: But we're redirecting the user using index no names. We'll find the same problem if we add more pages before Page 2 then

Comment: Well, my solution answers your original question. If you wanted to remove 'n' number of pages between X and Y, you should've mentioned that in the question first.

Comment: I'm using const index = this.viewCtrl.index - 2;  this.navCtrl.remove(1, index); to go back 2 pages and it works first time but next time time only goes back 1 page

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use the following function:

`popTo(page: Page | string | ViewController, opts?: NavOptions, done?: TransitionDoneFn): Promise<any>;`

explanation:

Pop to a specific view in the history stack. If an already created
     * instance of the page is not found in the stack, then it'll `setRoot`
     * to the nav stack by removing all current pages and pushing on a
     * new instance of the given page. Note that any params passed to
     * this method are not used when an existing page instance has already
     * been found in the stack. Nav params are only used by this method
     * when a new instance needs to be created.

Comment: I just checked there are problems with this function, may be thats why this is also not included in the documentation as well, but I read some where that if you cache the viewCtrl reference of that page that you want to move on and then keep it moving through your navigation via navParams then finally using that reference in this function will give you the desired result.

Comment: If we need to cache something I'd prefer to do this.navCtrl.remove(X, index) which is simpler. We can always do setRoot if we want to move to 1st page as well

Comment: yes thats a good point, also i thought its not just moving to root, its about moving to a specific point in the nav stack. Well its good that you got your answer and i also learned a thing.